# How to Highlight blank textfield in objective c on button click

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to highlight the particular textfield if textfield is empty on button click in objective c. Highlight means some text in red(field is empty) like error massage but in front of respective textfield only not in alert view

Answer (score 1):

First Import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your project.

Then you can get all subviews in array by calling subviews method:

```
-(void)checkTextFieldIsEmpty{

   NSArray *myarr = [self.view subviews];
   NSString *emptyTextFieldName = [[NSString alloc]init];

   for (int i = 0; i < myarr.count; i++) {
      if ([[myarr objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
         UITextField *tempTextField = (UITextField*)[myarr objectAtIndex:i];
            if (tempTextField.text.length >0) {
               NSLog(@"textfield have some text");
            }
            else{
               NSLog(@"textfield is empty");
                   //Change color here like following way
                   //tempTextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
                }
           }    
       }
    }
```

Comment: can tell me here why you add <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> Framework.

Comment: @HimanshuPatel   Click on your project name-->Build Phases-->Go to Link binary with Libraries-->click on +--> add QuartzCore.framework. then import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> in your file.

Comment: QuartzCore, also known as Core Animation, is an Objective-C framework that to declaratively build an animatable scene graph. CoreAnimation uses a unique rendering model where the graphics operations are run in a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 self.stremail=[self.txtemail.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
self.strpass=[self.txtpass.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];


if ((self.stremail.length==0) || (self.strpass.length == 0))
{
    if(self.stremail.length==0)
    {
    UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
    _txtemail.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_txtemail.placeholder attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color}];
    }else
    {
        UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
        _txtpass.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_txtpass.placeholder attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color}];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add the Right view in the text Field Like this

```
-(IBAction)yourButtonAction:(id)sender{

     if(yourTextField.text.lenght == 0){
           UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
          imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName.png/jpg"];

          self.yourTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
          self.yourTextField.rightView = imageView;
         }

   }
```

//   and in the Delegate methods of TextField

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;


     if(yourTextField.isEditing == YES){
          self.yourTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [US2FormValidator](https://github.com/ustwo/US2FormValidator) library. Just you have to add it in your project and give `US2ValidatorTextField` as class name with validation message and some properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get all sub views of view that contains `textFields` 
check if `subview` is kind of `UItextField` class and if it is empty then change the color:

```
for loop in self.view.subviews
{
   if([loop isKindOf:[UItextField class]] && loop.characters.count==0) {
      //change the Color of textField
   }
}
```